# Why QtWebEngineCore for macOS is so big in Qt6

Tags: size, qt6

Recently I'm investigating Qt6 so as to migrate my project to the latest Qt version. Finding that the QtWebEngineCore for macOS is so big in Qt-6.3.0, the size is 313M after stripped. And it's weird that after stripped the size doesn't decrease.

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 chengzhl  staff   313M Apr 16 07:33 QtWebEngineCore
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason now, this is because it's a universal library which supports both x86_64 and arm64 archs.

```
➜  ~ lipo ~/Qt6/6.3.0/macos/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/QtWebEngineCore -archs
x86_64 arm64
```